# Paraphrasing a sentence and changing the tone of it

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, transformer, machine-translation

I am trying to make a model that is capable of translating a sentence into a new and a better form. I would like the model to change the tone and also give it some character. I am using this in my web app UI, simply allowing the users to witness new description as they refresh the page. For example, "You are logged out" -> "Looks like you have logged out". Something of such sort, any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how they do it, but https://www.wordtune.com/#rewrite-demo is the most impressive paraphraser I've seen. Maybe they explain their approach somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the text augmentation techniques mentioned here.
https://github.com/makcedward/nlpaug/blob/master/example/textual_augmenter.ipynb